# Angularjs : how to show contents of ng-repeat with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I've been trying to show the contents of `ng-repeat`. I use Laravel 5.2, which apparently makes this task more complicated.

In case you haven't tried this, let me explain that using double curly braces (e.g. `{{ value }}`) is going to find a php variable  (`$value`), instead of properties in Angular controllers, if you use Laravel.

This can be solved by preceding with `@`, according to [the Laravel's documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data) Also, I learned that there are some other ways to show variables other than `{{ value }}`. Still, I can't show values of `ng-repeat` on HTML.

My code looks like this.

```
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="TableController as tc">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="s in tc.data.students">
        <td>@{{ s.name }}</td> //1st attempt
        <td>@{!! s.name !!}</td>     //2nd attempt
        <td ng-bind="s.name"></td>        //3rd attempt
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('angularApp', [])
    .controller('TableController', function(){
        this.data = {
            students: [
            @foreach($students as $student)
            "{!! $student !!}", //This can be replaced with {{ $student }}
            @endforeach
            ]
        };
    });
</script>
```

`$students` is an array, containing SQL objects called `student`. This comes from a Laravel's controller function.

**EDIT**
I usually use the `$scope` for controller properties, but for this occasion I must use `as` syntax for controllers. Therefore, I cannot use `$scope` to store variables for controllers.

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong? Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Try using `$scope.data` instead of `this.data`? And then, `ng-repeat="s in data.students"`. My guess is that doesn't come from Laravel/Angular curly braces use, but just that you don't know how Angular works?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('angularApp', [])
            .controller('TableController', function($scope){
                $scope.data = {
                    students: [
                        @foreach($students as $student)
                        "{!! $student !!}",
        @endforeach

                };
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, for this time, I'm required to use the `as` syntax for Angular controllers, meaning that I cannot use $scope in the exact same way you suggested. Anyways, Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do the same:

View:

```
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="TableController">
<input type="text" ng-model="searchBox">
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
        <td>@{{ student.name }}</td>            
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('angularApp', [])
.controller('TableController', function($scope){
    $scope.students: [
        @foreach($students as $student)
        "{!! $student !!}", //This can be replaced with {{ $student }}
        @endforeach
        ];

});
```

`$scope` is a fondamental notion in Angular: it makes data available in scope (in the controller or in the view). Some docs here : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

I suggest you to complete the official Angular tutorial, it would help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, however, I had to use the `as` syntax for controllers because of the request from the client. In other words, for this particular occasion, I'm not allowed to use `$scope` in the way you suggested. (Instead, I need to use the `this` expression. Still, I appreciate your advice!